# apt command unable to locate npm and node packages

Tags: node.js, linux, npm

My npm started to act funny, refusing to run scripts and to install packages, so I try to uninstall npm and node.

```
sudo apt-get purge npm
```

outputs that it's unable to locate it, same with node.

```
apt list --installed | grep node
```

outputs nothing.
Installation path is /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0/bin/node(npm). I have no idea what to do, honestly. Node still runs fine on its port and outputs to the console.

Shell ignores npm/node commands like

```
npm install
```

outputs     bash: npm: command not found

```
sudo apt-get purge node
```

outputs     Package 'node' is not installed, so not removed

Tried installing different node versions through nvm, also

Removed nvm using `rm -rf ~/.nvm`. Tried to look up post @l3l_aze posted, started w/

```
sudo curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
```

output was

```
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (1: Operation not permitted)
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
W: Problem unlinking the file /var/cache/apt/srcpkgcache.bin - RemoveCaches (13: Permission denied)
Error executing command, exiting
```

Answer (score 2):

The most important part to come out of this is to understand what you're using. NVM doesn't install node/npm/etc through apt or another package manager. It's effectively replacing the need for doing so.

Instead you need to use nvm to remove your node installation like `nvm uninstall 12.10.0`. Also possible to manually remove it something like `sudo rm -rf ~/.nvm/versions/node/v12.10.0`, but that shouldn't be necessary and also may not be the best idea.

Also note that when using NVM to manage node you *cannot* have NVM remove the current node version that's in use. So, unless you already have another version installed you'll have to get one before nuking it. To see what versions are installed locally run `nvm ls`. To see what versions are available to install run `nvm ls-remote`. To install the latest LTS version use the special identifier "lts/*", e.g. `nvm install lts/*`.

Comment: did it, but to no effect

Comment: Ouch, sounds like it's extra broken. What in particular did you try? Have you tried [uninstalling NVM itself](file:///android_asset/md/#uninstalling--removal)? This will also nuke node as it destroys `~/.nvm`. If you're going to reinstall it there's no need to remove the lines that load NVM into the shell, but it may append a second copy of them if they're left so make sure to check.

Comment: apt is unable to locate nvm package as well. Even which nvm outputs nothing, I tried apt purge on it, but to no effect. Isn't nvm just another apt package ?

Comment: No, NVM is just a "sourced shell function, not an executable binary" (from the docs). That's why it doesn't get reported by `which nvm`. Instead, the docs say to use `command -v nvm` to check that it's properly installed and working.

Comment: it outputs nvm lol. Any idea what should i do next ? I am newbie linux user, maybe I should reinstall Linux ? Am running MX18.3 (Continuum) currently.

Comment: That is the expected output from `command -v nvm`, so that's good. Can you edit your question to include what you've tried so far? It may work as a comment, but would fit better there and be more easily accessible to anyone else who may be able to help.

Comment: @fit_For_a_King Good edit, thank you. There are some things online that imply NVM works with MX Linux, but I can't personally test. If there's any chance you did anything that could've messed up the configuration it would be worth at least removing NVM completely (`rm -rf ~/.nvm`) and trying again before doing a full system reinstall. Just make sure to read through the directions in the NVM docs. I found an [mxlinux forum post](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?p=482209#p482209) with notes about playing with the official installer to make it work, but again can't test it.

Comment: updated the original comment, did not work, unfortunatley. Thanks for the effort, though